# How to get the total price of all the items in the basket?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the total price of all the items in the cart after adding items in the cart. The price should also increase when the quantity of each item is increased and also decrease when the quantity is decreased. Please help me with that,

The total variable in the cart class outputs null on the field where the total should be at.

The cart class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              tooltip: "Confirm Order",
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                //Leading
                leading: Text(("Total: ") +
                    item.sum.toString() +
                    "\n" +
                    item.category +
                    "\n" +
                    "R" +
                    item.price.toString()),

                //Title
                title: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    "(" +
                    item.counter.toString() +
                    ")"),
                //Subtitle
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.incrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),

                //Trailing
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.decrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The dish Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dish {
  final String category;
  final String brandName;
  final int price;

  int counter = 1;

  int count;
  int sum;

  int totalPrice() {
    return sum = price * counter;
  }

  void decrementCounter() {
    counter--;
  }

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
  }

  Dish({this.category, this.brandName, this.sum, this.price});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've two variable for price inside the Dish Class,

`prices` and `price`. Where `prices` is always null. and `price` is set by the constructor. So, in the `totalPrice` method, you're using `prices` which is wrong, you should use `price` there instead.

Comment: i replaced `prices` with `price` and changed the data type from `double` to `ìnt`, but it still outputs `null`  I updated my Dish class in my question

Comment: Have you checked if the price holds any value?

Comment: Also, the product list with name and price they are showing properly?